# PhpStorm does not detect my PHP 7 remote interpreter

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm, phpstorm-2016.1

So I'm using PhpStorm 2016.1.1 and I've been using a PHP 5.6 remote interpreter since I've started using this IDE.

The "remote" refers to a web dev server I have on my personal network.

So before my issue, I had the following the configuration:

[image]

As you can see, PhpStorm detects my PHP 5.6 version properly.

A few months ago, I switched to PHP 7 on my server so last week, I thought I would switch the interpreter too. So my PHP 7 interpreter is `/usr/bin/php` or `/usr/bin/php7.0`

The problem I'm facing is that none of those two works, **PhpStorm keeps giving me the error:**

> PHP version: Not installed

[image]

I **already double checked the permissions and both PHP 5.6 and 7 executables have the exact same permissions.** I also tried making a copy of the PHP 7 executable and chmod it to 777 but didn't help.

Also calling PHP from the console with the same user as the one in my remote configuration works perfectly:

```
user@webdev:/var/www$ php -v
PHP 7.0.12-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader (enabled) + Intrusion Protection from ioncube24.com (unconfigured) v6.0.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by ionCube Ltd.
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.12-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.4.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans
```

I tried to use the Invalidate Caches / Restart of PhpStorm but didn't help.

Now I'm running out of ideas so I'm wondering if someone here has a clue of what's going on here.

Comment: Check the `idea.log` for possible hints. Please also try PhpStorm 2016.3 EAP build (can be run in parallel as it stores IDE-wide settings in separate folder).

Comment: @LazyOne unfortunately nothing in the `idea.log` ( I mean nothing related to this configuration issue)

Comment: Try extra logging and check the logs -- it might give more info (the deployment log part): https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241115-How-to-Collecting-PhpStorm-WebStorm-debug-Logs (try clearing `idea.log` before that so it's shorter)

Comment: @LazyOne `idea.log` indeed helped me but only after upgrading to 2016.3 EAP ;) see my answer

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that there is unicode characters in my PHP config for some reasons:

[image]

Thus, that breaks the XML generated by the PHPStorm phpinfo.php file.

I haven't found a way to get rid of those unicode characters yet so I ended up hacking temporarily (you know that temp hack probably means I'll keep it like this forever right ? ^^) the `/home/<user>/.phpstorm_helpers/phpinfo.php` by replacing line 154:

```
"name" => htmlspecialchars($configurationOptionName)
```

With:

```
"name" => preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', htmlspecialchars($configurationOptionName))
```

Comment: Please file a ticket to [Issue Tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI) with your findings -- it will help others as well in form of proper fix in IDE (or you may get some hints with some possible misconfigurations etc in case if it's the reason here).

Comment: @LazyOne already done that ;) also I've opened a new question on ServerFault re: this weird unicode issue: http://serverfault.com/q/816089/382958

Comment: Can I have PhpStorm's ticket number? Would like to follow it there.

Comment: @LazyOne sure it's #809851

Comment: Oh .. so you have submitted it to Technical Support team (which is a correct way for initial issue) and not actual Issue Tracker. I guess it's OK -- they may convert it into actual Bug/Feature ticket if they think it's needed.